# PHP Regex statements

Tags: php, regex

With a post request, I'm trying to return a booking number to my iOS App. It posts the current date as a string which is written to a file on my server.
The logic is, that whenever the date from the last entry does not match the date passed in the post request, the booking number starts from `01`. If it *is* the same date, the booking number gets increased by one.

The text file I write my entries to looks like this:

```
2017-03-03, 1;
2017-03-03, 2;
2017-03-03, 3;
2017-03-03, 4;
2017-03-03, 5
```

I am using regex to find the last entry, comparing its date to the current and assigning the new booking number.
Here is my code:

```
if (preg_match_all("/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2},\s\d\z/", $textFileString, $entryArray)) {
    if (preg_match_all("/\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}/", $entryArray[0][0], $dateArray)) {
        if ($dateArray[0][0] == $currentDate) { //$currentDate's value comes from the post request
            if (preg_match_all("/\d\z/", $entry[0][0], $numberArray)) {
                $bookingNumber = $output_array[0][0]+1;
            }
        } else {
            $bookingNumber = 1;
        }
    }
}
```

Note: I do successfully write to the file.

Comment: So what's not working?

Comment: If you are interested in a single match, why use `preg_match_all`? Use `preg_match`. Also, `\z` matches the very end of string, what if there is a trailing newline? Change into `$`.

Comment: Well when I read bookingNumber from the json response inside my app, I get the value that I assigned to `$bookingNumber` before these regex statements

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I am trying to read the latest entry, which is obviously at the very end of the string.

Comment: What is the `$currentDate` value here? `2017-03-02`?

Comment: `$currentDate` gets its value from the post request. In this case (today) it is `2017-03-03`

Comment: Check this code: https://ideone.com/AQOjII, does it solve the issue?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137132/discussion-between-linus-g-and-wiktor-stribizew).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest switching to `preg_match` (since you only need to find a *single* match) and add capturing groups to the pattern so as to reduce the code a bit:

```
$textFileString = '2017-03-03, 1;
2017-03-03, 2;
2017-03-03, 3;
2017-03-03, 4;
2017-03-03, 5';
$currentDate = '2017-03-03';
if (preg_match("/(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}),\s(\d{1,2})\z/", $textFileString, $entryArray)) {
    if ($entryArray[1] == $currentDate) { //$currentDate's value comes from the post request
        $bookingNumber = $entryArray[2]+1;
    } else {
        $bookingNumber = 1;
    }

}
echo $bookingNumber;
```

See the [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/hF2l0g).

Note you may also replace `\z` with `$` since the `$` anchor matches at the end of the string (or before a final LF in the string) by default.

Now, `(\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}),\s(\d{1,2})\z` contains two capturing groups that you may access via `$entryArray[1]` and `$entryArray[2]`.